# ListView with horizontal layout and wrap from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wrappanel, itemspanel

I am force to use a ListView/listbox from code behind.
In that I have to put borders. I wish they wrapped on a new line when needed

```
ListView lsv = new ListView
{
    Width = 400,
    Height = 200,
    Background = Brushes.LimeGreen,
};
grdMain.Children.Add(lsv);

for (int iii = 0; iii < 15; iii++)
{
    Border b = new Border() { BorderThickness = new Thickness(3),
    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), Width = 50, Height = 50     
};
lsv.Items.Add(b);
lsv.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Parse("<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><WrapPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Stretch\"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>");
```

Now with that the effect is the following:
[image]

instead if I put a fixed width Width=\"300\"

```
lsv.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Parse("<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><WrapPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\" Width=\"300\"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>");
```

it works properly

[image]

the problem is that I can't put a fixed width for the wrap panel and I want it to extend to fill its parent.

Thank you in advance
Patrick

Comment: What happens if you set MaxWidth instead of Width? I mean, Width is just a suggestion, whereas MaxWidth is a contraint.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is it may be a timing issue as you're calling XamlReader.Parse *after* adding the elements whereas you're setting the width property before.

Comment: Try setting `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Disabled` in the code behind.

Comment: @JacobProffitt I put the command lsv.ItemsPanel = (ItemsPanelTemplate)XamlReader.Parse("<ItemsPanelTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><WrapPanel Orientation=\"Horizontal\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Stretch\"/></ItemsPanelTemplate>"); before the for cycle but nothing changed alas..

Comment: @JacobProffitt I changed to ListView lsv = new ListView
   {
    MaxWidth = 400,
    MaxHeight = 200,
    Background = Brushes.LimeGreen,
   }; but again no chance...

Comment: @MoonKnight where is the ScrollViewer property to be set?????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing the following...

```
ListView listView = new ListView();
var scrollViewer = Utils.GetDescendantByType(listView, typeof(ScrollViewer)) as ScrollViewer;
scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

Where you will have a helper method

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static Visual GetDescendantByType(Visual element, Type type)
    {
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        if (element.GetType() == type)
            return element;

        Visual foundElement = null;
        if (element is FrameworkElement)
            (element as FrameworkElement).ApplyTemplate();

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            Visual visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
            foundElement = GetDescendantByType(visual, type);
            if (foundElement != null)
                break;
        }
        return foundElement;
    }
}
```

Note, I have note compiled this code as am on a phone.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO. I was going to cry...thanx

Comment: Good answer and thorough and on the phone, no less. Well done.